# is it possible to Dynamically add/remove tiles from dashboard via power bi-embedded

Tags: powerbi-embedded

https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/v2-demo/index.html#

Hi,

was wondering if it's possible to dynamically add/remove tiles from the dashboard via power bi-embedded.  Imagine that the user wants to add there own tile and arrange it themselves in the dashboard.

Also is the tile a snapshot of the data or if the datasource updates will the data in the tiles get updated as well.

If this isn't currently supported, do you know what the time frame would this be supported or is there plans?

Thanks,
Derek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Power BI Embedded does not support **Pin to Dashboard** operation currently.

Comment: is there plans to support this?

Comment: There are, but not in the next few months.. you can upvote this feature in http://ideas.powerbi.com

Comment: @RBreuer Any idea if this is on the roadmap? - the ability for a user to create bespoke dashboards in app would be invaluable

Comment: There is no ETA on this, as this is a very low priority for the product team. you can always upvote in the ideas page (URL above)

Comment: @RBreuer Why is there not just parity with the API and the portal functionality? It just makes no sense that the API is so weak. The user voice is impossible to locate anything in because there are so many tickets that never get merged/managed. I assume it is covered bt this https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/13535403-create-a-report-dashboard-programatically-using-th - create dashboard dynamically

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would have to be dealt through some visibility property in an embedDashboardConfig structure definition. It is possible to show|hide specific visuals in a report page by modifying report embedReportConfig.You may take a look at Custom layout demo which is available online under "live showcases" tab on Power BI JavaScript Playground v2 demo. The demo basically reshapes the whole layout of reports dynamically through VisualContainer section visibility attributes. Unfortunately those features only apply to reports scope scenarios and are not yet available to Dashboards.